# Is there a gcc compiler option to capture formal and actual parameter type mismatch?

Tags: c, parameters, compiler-warnings, type-mismatch

I pass a float to a function expecting an int:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void p(int a){
  printf("%d\n",a);
}

int main(){
  float b;
  b=3.333f;
  p(b);
}
```

Is there a gcc compiler option which will warn about this mismatch? `gcc -Wall` does not raise warning.

Comment: `-Wconversion` does cause a warning in this case when using gcc as mentioned in one of the answers for the linked question.

Comment: -Wconversion works. My question is different from the linked question (mine is about formal-actual parameter mismach, the linked question is a simple assignment conversion) although -Wconversion works for both situations.

Comment: @YoujunHu matching of arguments to formal parameters is defined to behave like simple assignment

Comment: @M.M I asked a new question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56212992/is-there-a-gcc-compiler-option-that-help-capture-formal-and-actual-parameter-typ) for the case that the function definition is in another file. For this case,  `-Wconversion` does not help.

Comment: @YoujunHu well that is an entirely different scenario

Answer (score 1):

Use `-Wconversion` to get a warning for implicit conversions:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void p(int a)
{
    printf("%d\n", a);
}

int main()
{
    float b = 3.333f;
    p(b);  // to get a warning for this implicit conversion, use -Wconversion
}
```

```
./example.c:11:7: warning: conversion from 'float' to 'int' may change value
                           [-Wfloat-conversion]
   11 |     p(b);
      |       ^
```

See [Using the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC) - 3.8 Options to Request or Suppress Warnings](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)